# How to set std::tuple element by index?

Tags: c++, templates, indexing, tuples

One can get an element from `std::tuple` by index using `std::get`.
Analogically, how to *set* tuple's element by index?

Answer (score 177, accepted):

`std::get` returns a reference to the value. So you set the value like this:

```
std::get<0>(myTuple) = newValue;
```

This of course assumes that `myTuple` is non-const. You can even move items out of a tuple via `std::move`, by invoking it on the tuple:

```
auto movedTo = std::get<0>(std::move(myTuple));
```

Answer (score 27):

The non-const version of `get` [returns a reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/get). You can assign to the reference. For example, suppose `t` is tuple, then: `get<0>(t) = 3;`